# BASH: Search for several Keywords in file and highlight them

Tags: bash, grep, text-coloring

I want to search all files in a directory for a Keyword and color it, like:

```
grep -n "keyword1" * --color
```

Now I want to highlight all occurrences of `keyword2` and `keyword3` in an other color.

I managed

```
grep -n "keyword1 * |egrep --color "keyword2|keyword3|$'
```

this will color both last keywords but in the same color.
but I fail to set several different colors to work with a coloring from the first grep-statement. I don't know how to set the constant `GREP_COLORS` correctly

Comment: thanks, yes it is a doublicate more or less

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will do the job:

```
grep --color=always -n "keyword1" *  | GREP_COLOR='1;30;40'  grep --color keyword2
```

Comment: I needed to understand all options, so that's what I figured it out by now:
- --color=always keeps the word highlighted even through piped greps, so if you're looking for 3 or more words you need to set =always to all commands but the last one
- GREP_COLOR='1;30' means thickness 1 (bold) and color 30 (black, bad choice if you use a dark background)

I know GREP_COLOR can accept even more complex parameters but I just cannot find an exhaustive documentation
(+1 to this answer for the good solution btw)

Comment: It's well documented  in  `GREP_COLORS`  section in `grep man page`. According to the manpage `GREP_COLOR` is `deprecated  in favor  of  GREP_COLORS`.